# Solidity Smart Contracts redundant inheritance

Tags: ethereum, solidity, multiple-inheritance, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I'm reviewing OpenZeppelin's smart contracts and in many cases I find that there tends to be a redundant or duplicate inheritance.

```
contract ERC20 is IERC20, IERC20Metadata {}

interface IERC20 {}

interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {}
```

In this example, **ERC20** implements **IERC20Metadata** which already implements **IERC20**. Nonetheless, the contract implements both of them. I tried removing the redundant interfaces and it works just fine. Is there a reason for this? Is it for clarity or legibility purposes only?

Answer (score 2):

The author of this code states in a [comment](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/b8ab763581f8705fec306903659200fe753b68c3#r50176381):

> *It's technically not necessary, but it's good to be explicit.*